# Endless while loop with PlantUML

Tags: while-loop, plantuml, activity-diagram

Using PlantUML, the following results in an arrow into nowhere as exit for the loop. How do I get rid of the arrow to nowhere to get an endless loop?

```
start
while (Always)  is ( )
  :do something;
endwhile ( )
```

[image: See resulting picture here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the arrow:

```
while (Always)
  :do something;
endwhile
-[hidden]->
detach
```

[image: Endless loop]